# How to fix this css float problem?

Tags: css

css noob here, struggling to figure out how to make the *float:left* work.
The page that I am trying to fix is here: http://www.yshara.com

1) I would like to align the links: twitter and website on that page to the right of the profile page.

2) How to align the heading 'Joe Johnson' etc with the image-container top.

thanks for your help.

Comment: I wonder why don't you use a CSS Framework, as all this will be solved, http://www.blueprintcss.org/ or http://960.gs/ are fantastic for this kind job.

Comment: I looked at 960.gs a while back and it looked very primitive. blueprintcss looks good. Any resources to quickly get up to speed would be really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply **clearfix** to the parent div as opposed to placing one in the middle:

```
<div id="profile-frame" class="clearfix">
    <div class="left">

        <div class="photo">
            <img width="103" height="103" alt="TestProfile" src="../images/test_profile_1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="profile-details">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Joe Johnson, Basketball &amp; Atlanta</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="desc">
                Hi my name is Joe Johnson, I am 26 years old and live in Atlanta. I enjoy basketball and twitter. I will be achieving much bigger things once I get better teammates.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.atlantahawks.com/">website</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://twitter.com/JoeJoe2ATL">twitter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** sorry, didn'nt read your second question. The thing pulling your title down is the margin on `<h1>` tags. Add this in your CSS:

```
 .header h1{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you suggest how to fix the top alignment of the headline with the image? thanks.